# About the C++ return statement / Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been looking over the tutorial here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx, but I'm really confused on one point.

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return (int) msg.wParam;
```

I have no idea what they're doing with return there. I know return only works with one value. Why are there 2 things? I've looked at other tutorials and they all seem to use `return msg.wParam;`

Comment: That's a C-style cast, not a second value.  Get a good C++ book.

Comment: talnicolas and Luchian Grigore each give half your answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt - actually, there's nothing C++ about the question, I'd suggest changing the title and tags.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Evidently a C++ compiler is used.  There's quite a lot of code that behaves differently depending on whether it's compiled in C++ mode, so I'm against retagging `[c++]` questions as `[c]`.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I would say that there's nothing C++ in this question. (especially after looking at the linked page)

Comment: @KevinDTimm: It's not terribly important here, but `NULL` is defined differently in C++ vs C.  It's also possible (looking just at the excerpt) that some of the functions being called are being found in a class or a namespace instead of the Win32 headers.  Of course the MSDN page is a complete example showing that isn't the case.  I prefer for question askers to just tag with the language they're actually using, instead of trying to decide whether the C vs C++ differences are relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is casting the value of `msg.wParam` to an int. As you can see in the function declaration:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine,
               int nCmdShow)
```

the return type is `int`. I don't know exactly what the type of the property `wParam` is, but it is probably not an `int`, so it has to be explicitly cast to an int or it would not compile.

Comment: Not that it matters but I think `wParam` would be of type `WPARAM` which is `long` or something.

Comment: `wParam` isn't an `int`, but I'm pretty sure there is an implicit conversion.

Comment: The `wParam` field is indeed a `WPARAM`, which is a `UINT_PTR`, which is either `unsigned int` or `unsigned __int64` depending on whether the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

That code is probably part of a function that returns an `int`. Since `msg.wParam` can't be implicitly cast to an `int`, an explicit cast is required. It's basically equivalent to:

```
int ret = (int)msg.wParam;
return ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Why are there 2 things*

There are not two things: there is just the `wParam` field of the `msg` varaible (of type `MSG`  that is a `struct`) converted into `int`.